# Why is obj.constructor.prototype not always equal to obj.__proto__?

Tags: javascript, prototypal-inheritance

```js
function Product(name, price) {
  this.name = name;
  this.price = price;
}

const p1 = new Product('Pen', 20);
const p2 = Object.create(p1);

console.log(p1.constructor.prototype === p1.__proto__);  // true
console.log(p2.constructor.prototype === p2.__proto__);  // false
```

My understanding was these two are always equal (as in the first `console.log` statement).

But, while doing some tweaks I found this surprising result (second `console.log` statement).

Can someone please clear up my understanding about the relationship between `prototype` and `__proto__`. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This only works for instances created using `new` from constructors that follow the standard prototype pattern. These objects will inherit from the constructors `.prototype` object, which has a `.constructor` property pointing back to the constructor. This means when accessing the inherited `.constructor`, we can find the prototype object that we're inheriting on it.

However, it doesn't work for arbitrary objects that have their own `.constructor` property (e.g. `{constructor: null}`) or for objects that don't inherit directly from a constructor's prototype object, such as your `p2`.

To clarify what's happening in your code without using `new`:

```
const Product = Object.create(Function.prototype);
Product.prototype = Object.create(Object.prototype);
Product.prototype.constructor = Product;

const p1 = Object.create(Product.prototype);
p1.name = "Pen";
p1.price = 20;
console.assert(Product.prototype == Object.getPrototypeOf(p1));
console.assert(!p1.hasOwnProperty("constructor") && p1.constructor == Product);
console.assert(p1.constructor.prototype == Product.prototype);
console.assert(p1.constructor.prototype == Object.getPrototypeOf(p1));

const p2 = Object.create(p1);
console.assert(p1 == Object.getPrototypeOf(p2));
console.assert(!p2.hasOwnProperty("constructor") && p2.constructor == p1.constructor);
```

Comment: But, I didn't understand how `console.log(p2.constructor.prototype === p1.__proto__);` turns out to be `true`? I'm confused about relationship between `p1` and `p2` in terms of prototypal inheritance.

Comment: @GeniusGo `p2.constructor` is inherited from `p1.constructor` (which in turn is inherited from `Product.prototype.constructor`).

Comment: one more question, I understood that `p1.__proto__` points to `p1.constructor.prototype`, but where does `p2.__proto__` point to?

Comment: @GeniusGo `p1` - see `const p2 = Object.create(p1);
console.assert(p1 == Object.getPrototypeOf(p2));`

Comment: Ohhk, got it!! Thank you so much @Bergi!